# Cookie Clicker cheat functions comparison

Tags: javascript

So I was looking up Cookie Clicker auto click scripts and found these 2 functions.

```
var autoClicker = setInterval(Game.ClickCookie, <milliseconds interval>);
```

and

```
var autoClicker = function(clicksAtOnce, repeatInterval) {
  var cheated = false;
  var intoTheAbyss = function() {
    if(!cheated) {
      cheated = true;
      for(var i = 0; i < clicksAtOnce; i++) {
        Game.ClickCookie();
        Game.lastClick = 0;
      }
      cheated = false;
    }
  };
  return setInterval(intoTheAbyss, repeatInterval);
}; 
autoClicker(<amount of clicks>, <milliseconds interval>);
```

Each function simulates a click for the cookie for however many times during the interval. The description for the second function says `The auto-click cheat above(first function) can only click as fast as the CPU can handle. To produce an even faster effect, use:`

So my question is how is the second function faster than the first? What is the point of the closure in the second function?(It still automatically clicks without the closure part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the explanation provided is, strictly speaking, true. It's more that in the first one, you're sending one function call every `<milliseconds interval>`. In the second, you're sending `<amount of clicks>` function calls. If you sent 100 clicks every 100 milliseconds with the second, that'd be the same as running the first on a 1 millisecond interval. However, you can't go lower than a 1 millisecond interval, so you can try to run the second one at, say, 100 clicks per every millisecond, which would necessarily be faster than the first.

The `var cheated` placement in that function stops the `intoTheAbyss` function from spawning `clicksAtOnce` new `cheated` booleans each time it runs. It's just there to save memory.

Comment: Ah I get it now, with the first you're limited to 1 ClickCookie() per 1 milisecond max...But for my next question what is the point of the closure in the second function?